# How do I find the minimum of a numpy matrix? (In this particular case)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a numpy matrix as follows

```
[['- A B C D E']
['A 0 2 3 4 5']
['B 2 0 3 4 5']
['C 3 3 0 4 5']
['D 4 4 4 0 5']
['E 5 5 5 5 0']]
```

How do I find the **minimum** in this matrix along with the **index** of this minimum, **excluding** all of the zeros when considering the minimum?

I tried several methods I saw online, but I would almost always get the following error: `TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type`

I would appreciate any new solutions that I can try and check if it works?

Comment: That looks like a `(6, 1)` array where each row contains a single long string...

Comment: It seems like the matrix has been parsed incorrectly. This is not really a matrix yet, it has strings instead of numbers in it.

Comment: Could you add your code to the question?

Answer (score 2):

You need to go back to the drawing board with your 'numpy' matrix, that is not an matrix, but a list of list of (single) string.

```
x =['- A B C D E',
'A 0 2 3 4 5',
'B 2 0 3 4 5',
'C 3 3 0 4 5',
'D 4 4 4 0 5',
'E 5 5 5 5 0']

# Preprocess this matrix to make it a matrix
x = [e.split() for e in x]
numbers = set("0123456789")
xr = [[float(e) if all(c in numbers for c in e) and e != "0" else float("inf") for e in l] for l in x]
```

Everything that's not a number or 0 is marked as float(inf) to not get into the way of minimum calculation:

```
[[inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf],
 [inf, inf, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0],
 [inf, 2.0, inf, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0],
 [inf, 3.0, 3.0, inf, 4.0, 5.0],
 [inf, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, inf, 5.0],
 [inf, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, inf]]
```

You can then easily use numpy's `argmin` and `unravel_index` to get what you want.

```
xrn = np.array(xr)
index = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(xrn), xrn.shape)

# RESULT: (1, 2)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. Just one more thing, how do I convert what the list of strings I have given in my question to the format that you have given in the answer. As your answer has only one set of brackets.

Comment: replace the first code line `[e.split() for e in x]` with `[e[0].split() for e in x]`