# How do I change the following data structure to a numpy matrix and a numpy array (separately)?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

How do I convert the following data structure to a **numpy matrix** and a **numpy array**? 
 
This is what I have currently:

```
[['- A B C D E']
['A 0 2 3 4 5']
['B 2 0 3 4 5']
['C 3 3 0 4 5']
['D 4 4 4 0 5']
['E 5 5 5 5 0']]
```

Comment: try `arrayA = numpy.asarray(T)` where `T=your_array_above`

Comment: sequal to https://stackoverflow.com/q/55517960

Comment: didn't change anything unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [['- A B C D E'], ['A 0 2 3 4 5'], ['B 2 0 3 4 5'], ['C 3 3 0 4 5'], ['D 4 4 4 0 5'], ['E 5 5 5 5 0']]
b = [y.split(' ') for x in a for y in x]


import numpy as np

numpy_array = np.array(b)
```

output

```
array([['-', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
   ['A', '0', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
   ['B', '2', '0', '3', '4', '5'],
   ['C', '3', '3', '0', '4', '5'],
   ['D', '4', '4', '4', '0', '5'],
   ['E', '5', '5', '5', '5', '0']], dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: accept as an answer then :D and BTW your array was not in correct python format. I tried adding commas but there were only 5 characters and stackoverflow wanted more.